# Use LiveData without Lifecycle Owner

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I could not find any information, if it's a bad idea to use LiveData without a lifecycle owner. And if it is, what could be the alternative?

Let me give you just a simple example

```
class Item() {
    private lateinit var property: MutableLiveData<Boolean>

    init {
        property.value = false
    }

    fun getProperty(): LiveData<Boolean> = property

    fun toggleProperty() {
        property.value = when (property.value) {
            false -> true
            else -> false
        }
    }
}

class ItemHolder {

    private val item = Item()

    private lateinit var observer: Observer<Boolean>

    fun init() {
        observer = Observer<Boolean> { item ->
            updateView(item)
        }
        item.getProperty().observeForever(observer)
    }

    fun destroy() {
        item.getProperty().removeObserver(observer)
    }

    fun clickOnButton() {
        item.toggleProperty();
    }

    private fun updateView(item: Boolean?) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure, you can do this, but if your item holder is tied to something with a lifecycle, it's probably a bad idea because you might get updates when your lifecycle object is not in a started state. If that isn't an issue, ok. What you have is similar to rx Java and manually subscribing and unsubscribing to an observable.

Comment: Agreed. Use `LiveData` with activities/fragments. Use RxJava for things not tied to the UI.

Answer (score 12):

You can register an observer without an associated LifecycleOwner object using the

```
observeForever(Observer) method
```

like that:

```
 orderRepo.getServices().observeForever(new Observer<List<Order>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<Order> orders) {
               //
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 5):

You can register an observer without an associated LifecycleOwner object using the `observeForever(Observer)` method. In this case, the observer is considered to be always active and is therefore always notified about modifications. You can remove these observers calling the `removeObserver(Observer)` method.

**Ref**
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata.html#work_livedata

Answer (score 3):

For me `LiveData` has two benefits:

1. It aware of life cycle events and will deliver updates only in an appropriate state of a subscriber (`Activity`/`Fragment`).
2. It holds the last posted value, and updates with it new subscribers.

As already been said, if you're using it out of the life cycle components (`Activity`/`Fragment`) and the delivered update could be managed anytime, then you can use it without life cycle holder, otherwise, sooner or later, it may result in a crash, or data loss.

As an alternative to the `LiveData` behavior, I can suggest a `BehaviourSubject` from `RxJava2` framework, which acts almost the same, holding the last updated value, and updating with it new subscribers.